# Spring Data MongoDB how to set index ttl from system property

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb

Preferably, using the `@Indexed` annotation, or some other declarative way, is it possible to inject a system property, preferably using SPeL.

I have tried the following but found `expireAfterSeconds` gives error because it wants an int:

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "#{@xyzUpdates.collectionName}")
public class UpdatesFromXyz {

    @Id
    @Field("resourceId")
    private UUID resourceId;

    @Indexed(expireAfterSeconds = "#{@xyzUpdates.maxRecords}")
    private LocalDate updateDate;

}
```

and my properties class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("xyz.updates")
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
public class XyzUpdates {

    private String collectionName = "updatesFromXyz";
    private int maxRecords;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SpringData MongoDB 2.2 you can use [expireAfter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/index/Indexed.html#expireAfter--) which accepts numeric values followed by their unit of measure or a Spring template expression.